# How To Display All Desired Elements From A List<Object> To The Console (C#)

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio, object

So I'm making a menu the user can use to view movies, add movies, and delete movies. Right now I have the menu completed to the point where if the user input is the number 1 it should display the movie title, year, director, and summary of that movie in another screen. I have a foreach loop that I'm using the display that particular movie's title, year, director, and summary but when I run my program it only shows the title and year and that's it. How can I show all 4 of those at once in the console? Code is below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace MovieLibrary
{
    // Should contain data: an address and list of movie objects.
    // MUST include a dynamic 'MENU' of MOVIES

    public class Library
    {
        // Fields
        private string _directory = "../../output/";
        private string _file = "Movies.txt";
        private List<Movie> _movies;

        public Library()
        {
            _movies = new List<Movie>();
            Load();

            bool menuRunning = true;

            while (menuRunning)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Pick a number. Any number.");

                string userOption = Console.ReadLine();

                while (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userOption))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please do not leave this blank.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Pick a number. Any number.");
                    userOption = Console.ReadLine();
                }

                if (userOption == "1")
                {
                    string montyTitle;
                    int montyYear;
                    string montyDirector;
                    string montySummary;

                    foreach (Movie movie in _movies)
                    {
                        if (movie.Title == "Monty Python and the Holy Grail")
                        {
                            montyTitle = movie.Title;
                            Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", montyTitle);
                        }
                        if (movie.Year == 1975)
                        {
                            montyYear = movie.Year;
                            Console.WriteLine("Year: {0}", montyYear);
                        }
                        if (movie.Director == "Terry Gilliam & Terry Jones")
                        {
                            montyDirector = movie.Director;
                            Console.WriteLine("Director: {0}", montyDirector);
                        }
                        if (movie.Summary == "Monty Python and the Holy Grail is about a ragtag group, the knights of the round table, assembled by the Great King Arthur to embark on a quest given by God to find the Holy Grail.")
                        {
                            montySummary = movie.Summary;
                            Console.WriteLine("Summary: {0}\r\n", montySummary);
                        }
                    }
                }

                else if (userOption == "2")
                {
                    // RE

                }

                else if (userOption == "3")
                {

                    // Alien

                }

                else if (userOption == "4")
                {
                    // DP

                }
                else if (userOption == "5")
                {
                    // The Avengers
                }
                else if (userOption == "6")
                {
                    // Zombieland

                }
                else if (userOption == "7")
                {
                    // BTLC

                }
                else if (userOption == "8")
                {
                    // The Thing

                }
                else if (userOption == "9")
                {
                    // CITW


                }

            }
        }


        //Loads the text file
        private void Load()
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(_directory + _file))
            {
                string text;

                while ((text = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                    string[] contents = text.Split(':');

                    Movie newLibrary = new Movie(contents[0], int.Parse(contents[1]), contents[2], contents[3]);
                    _movies.Add(newLibrary);

                }

            }
        }
        // Allows the user to view the list of movies
        private void View()
        {
            Console.Clear();

            foreach (Movie movie in _movies)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{movie.Title,-10}{"\n" + movie.Year,-10}{"\n" + movie.Director,-10}{"\n" + movie.Summary + "\r\n",-10}");

            }
        }
    }

    // Allows the user to add any new movies they would like to the list of movies in the text file
    /*public static void Add()
    {

    }

    // Allows the user to remove any movies they would like from the text file
    public static void Remove()
    {

    }*/
}
```

Comment: Do any movies contains a director with the exact text and casing as `"Terry Gilliam & Terry Jones"`

Comment: Yes. In my Movies.txt file that the streamreader is reading from there are two directors by that name.

Comment: You kinda need to show us that file; you didn't exactly answer the general's question, which was if any movie has a director cited precisely as "Terry Gillam & Terry Jones", exact case, no trailing spaces etc. You said "those two guys are mentioned in the file" - which could be entirely irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand your question.
It might be that the `if (movie.Director == "Terry Gilliam & Terry Jones")` is not going inside the if.

Maybe I can propose something different(?)

You do not need the `foreach` loop to iterate the list.
You can get items from your `_movies` in 2 different ways:

1. Convert to array: `var _myMoviesArray = _movies.ToArray();` and access them by an index (`Console.WriteLine(_myMoviesArray[userOption].Title)`);
2. Or use `Console.WriteLine(_movies.IndexAt(userOption).Title)`.

For printing in the console, instead of:
`Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", montyTitle);`
you can do:
`Console.WriteLine($"Title: {movie.Title}");`

And I think that you do not need to check the `if(movie.Title == "Monty Python and the Holy Grail")`. If you access by the userOption index, you can get directly to the Movie in your array.

Comment: So I did convert my list to an array and accessed it using the index of the element. It's not working quite right yet but it's a lot less code than I had before and works better so I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which part is bothering you exactly, but I was bored and decided to do a simple PoC of segregated code for you. I've defined a simple repository to manipulate your entity data and created a specific implementation of it targeting movies. I've implemented in-memory storage of your movies which could have any underlying implementation, such as text file or you could keep it in memory and store in the library itself once you finish modifying in-memory state. You can expand it, modify it, or discard it entirely if you don't like it.

**Repository interface definition**

```
namespace MovieLibrary
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    internal interface IRepository<T, K>
    {
        IEnumerable<T> Get();

        IEnumerable<T> Get(Func<T, bool> condition);

        T Get(K guid);

        void Add(T entity);

        void Remove(T guid);
    }
}
```

**Movie repository implementation**

```
namespace MovieLibrary
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    internal class MovieRepository
        : IRepository<Movie, Guid>
    {
        // In-memory storage, can be replaced with anything else.
        private readonly ISet<Movie> movies;

        public MovieRepository(IEnumerable<Movie> initialState = null)
        {
            this.movies = initialState?.ToHashSet() ?? new HashSet<Movie>();
        }

        public void Add(Movie movie) => movies.Add(movie);
        public IEnumerable<Movie> Get() => movies;
        public IEnumerable<Movie> Get(Func<Movie, bool> condition) => movies.Where(condition);
        public Movie Get(Guid guid) => movies.SingleOrDefault(movie => movie.Id == guid);
        public void Remove(Movie movie) => movies.Remove(movie);
    }
}
```

**Movie definition**

```
namespace MovieLibrary
{
    using System;

    public class Movie
    {
        public Movie(string title, int year, string director, string summary)
        {
            this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            this.Title = title;
            this.Year = year;
            this.Director = director;
            this.Summary = summary;
        }

        public Guid Id { get; }
        public string Title { get; }
        public int Year { get; }
        public string Director { get; }
        public string Summary { get; }

        public override bool Equals(object other) => other is Movie movie && movie.Id == this.Id;
        public override int GetHashCode() => HashCode.Combine(Id);
        public override string ToString() => string.Format(
            "-- Details --{0}{0}Title: {1}{0}Year: {2}{0}Director: {3}{0}Summary: {4}",
            Environment.NewLine,
            this.Title,
            this.Year,
            this.Director,
            this.Summary);
    }
}
```

**Library itself**

```
namespace MovieLibrary
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    public class Library
    {
        private readonly IRepository<Movie, Guid> repository;
        private readonly IDictionary<int, Movie> menuOptions;

        public Library()
        {
            this.repository = this.InitializeRepository();
            this.menuOptions = this.repository.Get()
                .Select((movie, index) =>
                    new { Ordinal = index + 1, Movie = movie })
                .ToDictionary(
                    item => item.Ordinal,
                    item => item.Movie);
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the movie library! Pick a movie you'd like to watch...");

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Movie> option in menuOptions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{option.Key}: {option.Value.Title}");
            }

            int selectedOrdinal = 0;
            Movie selectedMovie = null;

            do
            {
                Console.Write("Select option: ");
                string input = Console.ReadLine();

                if (!int.TryParse(input, out selectedOrdinal))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please pick the existing option from the list...");
                    continue;
                }

                this.menuOptions.TryGetValue(selectedOrdinal, out selectedMovie);
            }
            while (selectedMovie == null);

            Console.WriteLine("Thank you for picking our movie library! Your movie will start in a second...");

            Console.WriteLine(selectedMovie);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private IRepository<Movie, Guid> InitializeRepository()
        {
            // Mocking the initial data of library. You could load it from file instead.
            IEnumerable<Movie> movies = Enumerable
                .Range(1, 10)
                .Select(ordinal => new Movie(
                    $"Title {ordinal}",
                    DateTime.UtcNow.Year + ordinal,
                    $"Some Director {ordinal}",
                    $"Some dummy summary text {ordinal}"));

            return new MovieRepository(movies);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I get you to do one thing?

Turn the computer off (maybe after printing the problem statement) and sit down with a pencil and paper

Think about the problem in English (or your native language)

- You have a file of movie info, one movie per line
- You need to read the file, take input from the user that is a numerical index of the movie in the file lines, and show info about that movie in the console

Reason I'm asking you to turn the computer off is when sitting with visual studio open and a problem statement there is a great temptation to start writing code before thinking about what needs to be written. It's like being asked to build a bridge and you immediately march off to the builders yard and place an order for 10000 bricks - the first step to building a bridge is to find out all the requirements, draw it, make some calculations, think about what it has to support now and in the future. Building a bridge is a big task, this programming one you have is a relatively small task but it's big to you because you're just starting out. Once you learn the value of these pre-programming scoping exercises I promise you you'll use them throughout your entire career.

The problems will get bigger but the approach will remain the same; putting your algorithm on paper will help immensely, and should be viewed like writing an essay plan, or forming a sentence in your mind in English because you're an English native, rearranging it to how the Spanish person would say it, then translating it to Spanish words and speaking it. Everything you do when engineering software will be an exercise in translation, from headline overview, to detailed overview, to fine grained processes, eventually to computer code

You may always think in English and have to translate your English thoughts to c# actions; you need to write the process down in English first. Eventually you'll think in C# for some things, but it'll always mix with English, especially when dealing with normal users

Instead of pen and paper, you could also do this in c# comments then translate underneath them (and end up with nicely commented code, bonus) but as a beginner you'll get a lot more out of the visualization exercise of pen and paper. You can easily create flow diagrams, side notes, box outs, and rub things out - treeware approach will always help

So your algorithm might look like this

- read all the lines out of the file
- work through them one by one
- turn the line into a movie object -- callout note to self, need a movie object, what does it look like?
- add it to a collection of Movie objects
- that's the reading part done -- should store that collection of movies somewhere. Should make that reading part a self contained thing
- I now know how many movies I read out of the file because I have a collection with a count
- ask the user for an index
- print the movie at that index. No, wait. Stuff in c# is zero based so if the user wants movie 1, that will be in index 0 of the list/array/whatever -- remember to do a -1!!
- ask the user for another index - this is repetitive, so I probably need a loop. Another note to self, need a way to get out of the loop

Then you might add

- printing a movie needs breaking down
- should have a separate bit of code that prints a movie
- oh, there was that lecture about ToString and how it can be used to make a string representation of a custom object. Note to self- make a ToString in movie, then can just print the movie object and it will be ToStringed and nicely formatted automatically

---

The next thing I'll ask you to do, and it's a big ask, is to temporarily (or perhaps permanently) set aside all the code you wrote already. Some bits are usable, some are a mess of jumbled thoughts with no clear algorithm

Your movie class is probably ok

Your View method contains bits that would be useful for ToString

The method that reads the file is OK too

Start simple, with a static void main that first reads the movies (calls a ReadLibrary method, that returns a List<> of Movies) and enters a loop that shows the user a menu

Ask for input, just the movie index to be printed - none of that saving, adding new movies etc. Gotta keep it simple to start

Print the movie out, loop round again

With what you have already in the reading, the movie class, turning that view into an override ToString, you should be able to complete the current task in about 10 or fewer lines of code. If you go significantly over this (and you have currently) then your thinking has gone wrong

For example, you're asking for input and then you're saying "if they entered 1 then else if they entered 2 then..."

Take their input, turn it into a number and show the movie at that number (less one) in the collection. This makes it truly dynamic. Consider what will happen if they enter 999999 for a laugh and your movie collection only has 10 movies. Put a check in to stop it breaking. You might go back to your paper and where it says "ask the user for an index" you might add "and ensure that it isn't a crazy value"

Have an AskString method that takes a string question, prints the question and asks for input and returns it

Have an AskInt method that uses the AskString method and parses its return value to an int. extend the method to take another two parameters as well as the question- lower bound and upper bound. If the user enters a number outside the bounds, repeat the AskString until they enter a sensible value

---

I cannot, in good conscience, do your homework for you but I present this answer as educating you as to how to solve your own problem. All the bits you need are already present in what you've written *somewhere* but they lack structure and forethought

I've no qualms repeatedly editing this answer to  address further queries you have- drop a comment as to what is needed

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, if your other movies have duplicate titles, years, etc., " if (movie.Title == "Monty Python and the Holy Grail") " cannot find a movie accurately.

Your loop " while (menuRunning){} "  code can change to the following code:

```
while (menuRunning)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pick a number. Any number.");

            try
            {
                int userOption = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Clear();
                var _myMoviesArray = _movies.ToArray();
                Console.WriteLine("Title:{0}\nYear:{1}\nDirector:{2}\nSummary:{3}\n", _myMoviesArray[userOption].Title, _myMoviesArray[userOption].Year, _myMoviesArray[userOption].Director, _myMoviesArray[userOption].Summary);
            }
            catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine("please enter the number in the correct format."); }
        }
```

[My test document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYDnp.jpg)

[Code running result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJc6G.gif)